# What is the correct representation for this equation?

Tags: complex-numbers

I tried to draw in the plane the next equation:
$$1<|z+i|<2$$
I did
$$1<\sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2}<2$$
$$1<x^2+(y-1)^2<4$$
Do I have two circles here? The teacher draw only the outer circle $x^2+(y-1)^2<4$. Why was the inner circle not drawn?

Comment: There is something wrong here. For $z=z+iy$, we have $|z+i|=|x+i(1+y)|=\sqrt{x^2+(1+y)^2}$, so your solution is wrong, but also the solution of your teacher seems wrong.

Comment: Apart from the wrong minus sign, the inner circle is essential. For instance $z=-i$ satisfies $|z+i|<4$, but certainly not $|z+i|>1$. They should be the circles with radius $1$ and $2$ centered at $(0,-1)$.

Comment: really i should draw a ring, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $|z+i|$ is simply the distance between $z=x+iy$ and $-i$. So the searched number $z$ is such that its distance from $-i$ must be greater than $1$ and the same distance must be less than $2$.

This means that, in the Argand plane, it is a point external to the circle of radius $1$ centered at $(0,-1)$ and internal to the circle centered at the same point but with radius $2$.

In other words, it is a point $(x,y)$ such that:

$$
\begin{cases}
x^2+(1+y)^2>1\\
x^2+(1+y)^2<4
\end{cases}
$$

[image]